# DataView and get a bigger image

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

I am applying this sample. http://examples.ext.net/#/DataView/Basic/Overview/
it is basic data view implementation. What I wanna do with this sample ,when click the image inside data view,show the image as a bigger picture. How I can do that? Is there any method related to the image which fire.

Comment: I gusss I need an event image_clcik_event or somethimg like this ,on client side

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some kind of `lightbox plugin`. They are so many with jquery. Have a look at below mention links

1. http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/
2. http://fancybox.net/
3. http://finegoodsmarket.com/view/
   ...
   ...